# Is there a way of proving that if $A$ is an infinite set and $x\not\in A$ then $|A|=|A\cup\{x\}|$ without relying on the axiom of choice.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Let $A$ be an arbitrary infinite set and $x\not\in A$. I want to find a bijection between $A$ and
$A\cup\{x\}$.

**Proof 1:** A possible proof of that is to play with cardinal numbers as follows: Let $\kappa,\lambda$
be cardinal numbers such that $\kappa$ is infinite and $\lambda\leq \kappa$. Then

$$ \kappa\leq\kappa+\lambda\leq\kappa+\kappa=\kappa $$

and hence, Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem implies that $\kappa+\lambda=\kappa$, which for $\lambda=1$ implies
the desired result.

**Proof 2:** Another way of proving it is the following: We know that since $A$ is infinite there exists a countably infinite proper subset of $B\subseteq A$. Then, it is easy to see that $B$ can be partitioned as $B=B_{1}\cup B_{2}$, where $B_{1},B_{2}$ are countably infinite subsets of $B$. In particular, there exists a bijection $g:B\to B_{1}$. Hence, by writing $A=B\cup(A\setminus B)$, we see that the map $f:A\to B_{1}\cup(A\setminus B)$ where

$$ f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} x, & x\in A\setminus B \\
g(x), & x\in B\end{matrix}\right. $$

is a bijection between $A$ and its proper subset $B_{1}\cup(A\setminus B)$. Then, using this fact we proceed of proving the desired result. Let $C\subseteq A$ be a proper subset of $A$ such that $|C|=|A|$.
Let $h:A\to C$ be a bijection. Let also $y\in A\setminus C$. Obviously, we have that $|A|\leq|A\cup\{x\}|$. For the other direction observe that the map $f:A\cup\{x\}\to A$ where

$$ f(a)=\left\{\begin{matrix} h(a), & a\in A \\
y, & a=x\end{matrix}\right. $$

is 1-1 and so $|A\cup\{x\}|\leq |A|$. Then, again from Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem, we derive the equality.

**Question:** My question is whether I can prove this fact without relying in the axiom of choice.
I know that Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem is independent from AC but the proofs of the facts:

- if $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal then $\kappa+\kappa=\kappa$, and
- if $A$ is an infinite set then it contains a countably infinite proper subset

rely in AC (as far as those proofs that I know). However, it seems to me that the statement $|A\cup\{x\}|=|A|$ is very simple to rely in AC and can be proven without it, though I may be completely wrong.
Any comments?

Comment: Cantor–Bernstein is not independent from AC. That would mean that it is neither provable nor refutable from ZFC.

Comment: You didn't define *infinite*? Do you mean Dedekind infinite? Or did you mean Tarski infinite. If the latter then you cannot prove that since we can indeed have a set $A$ that is Tarski infinite but Dedekind finite, and so $|A+1| > |A|$. However if the former then I think its provable without choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a bijection $f:A\cup\{x\}\to A$, then consider the sequence
recursively defined by $x_0:=x$, $x_{n+1}:=f(x_n)$. Then $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,\},$
is a countable infinite subset of $A$. So $|A\cup\{a\}|=|A|$ is equivalent to
$A$ having a countable infinite subset.

I think the theorem that states that
an infinite set has a countable infinite subset requires a weak form of
Choice.

Comment: Very nice idea! I think so too but is this indeed the case?

Comment: Yes, it is.${}$